# Biblatex alphanumeric reference with organization

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have this bib entry and using biblatex with biber. When I set it with this options:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=true, doi=false, style=ieee-alphabetic, sorting=nyt, maxnames=5]{biblatex}


@misc{WWRFBookOfVisions:2001,
  author =       {},
  title =        {{WWRF Book of Visions - Visions of the Wiresless World}},
  organization =  {{Wireless World Research Forum}},
  year =         "2001",
  month =        {dec},
  url =          {http://www.wireless-world-research.org},
}
```

The reference is genrated as [01]. Is there any way of setting it to the Organization+Year?

Thanks

Comment: Just make the `organization` the `author`. `biblatex` is normally fine with *corporate authors*.

Comment: That's the simple way... but it works. I also did it, but was willing to know how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: Well, if the `orgnaization` is indeed the proper author of the work, then this *is* the proper way to do this (see 2.3.3 *Corporate Authors and Editors*, p. 31 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). Of course one could manipulate the label generation to also include the `organization` if necessary, but I don't feel that this is the right direction to take.

Comment: @moewe p. 30 in my copy. In addition to what moewe said, don't make an empty author for entries which really don't have one. If there really is no author, don't put the author field in the bib entry. While that's not the case here, it does sometimes apply. As it stands you are telling the system that there *is* an author and that author's name is an empty string!

Comment: @cfr Well, let's not quibble about page numbers (it seems to be page 31 in version 2.9a, that is the version one gets if one links to CTAN right now). But good point about the empty `author` field. Biber normally produces a warning for empty fields, along the lines of `The field 'author' in entry 'WWRFBookOfVisions:2001' cannot be null, deleting it.` the field is subsequently ignored and does not appear in the `.bbl` file. SO while it has no adverse effect with Biber I'm not sure about BibTex, and it is bad style anyway.